# Extending the Twig trans_default_domain with a variable?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a long Twig file like this:

```
...
<th>
    {{('tree.overview.panel.column.name')|trans({},'jury')}}
</th>
<th>
    {{('tree.overview.panel.column.length')|trans({},'jury')}}
</th>
...
```

Using the trans_default_domain() I managed to shorten it to this:

```
{% trans_default_domain "jury" %}
...
<th>
    {{('tree.overview.panel.column.length')|trans }}
</th>
<th>
    {{('tree.overview.panel.column.phase')|trans }}
</th>
...
```

But I would like to create something even shorter and easier to maintain like this:

```
{% trans_default_domain "jury" %}
{% trans_default_tree = 'tree.overview.panel.column.' %}
...
<th>
    {{trans_default_tree+('length')|trans}}
</th>
<th>
    {{trans_default_tree+('phase')|trans}}
</th>
...
```

Is this possible without writing an extension? Or is using an extension just the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this for short syntax :

```
{% trans_default_domain "jury" %}
{% set trans_default_tree = 'tree.overview.panel.column.' %}
...
<th>
    {{(trans_default_tree~'length')|trans}}
</th>
<th>
    {{(trans_default_tree~'phase')|trans}}
</th>
...
```

That is all i can think of to do what you want, you can use variables and '~' to concatenate the strings and apply the trans filter on the whole thing with brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Nawfals solution is perfect if you don't want to use an extension, but because I was looking for something more flexibile, I created an extension and it works just great. The extension has a setter and a getter, so now I can set my variables
directly in the extension function and then get the result. Furthermor, the setter works for every included page.

```
{% trans_default_domain "jury" %}
{{ set_tree_base('tree.overview.panel.column.') }}
...
<th>
    {{ (get_tree('name'))|trans }} // Also works like this: get_tree('name')|trans
</th>
<th>
    {{ (get_tree('phase'))|trans }}
</th>
...
```

The class in `src/Your/Namespace/Twig/Extensions/TranslateExtension.php` :

```
class TranslateExtension extends \Twig_Extension{

var $tree = false;

public function getFunctions() {
    return array(
     'set_tree_base' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'setTreeBase'),
     'get_tree' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getTree')
    );
}

public function getTree ($string) {
    return $this->tree . $string;
}

public function setTreeBase ($string) {
    $this->tree = $string;
}

public function getName() {
    return 'full_tree_node';
}
}
```

Don't forget to register the twig extension in YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
your_namespace.twig.extension:
    class: Your\Namespace\Twig\Extensions\TranslateExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```